# WordPress query custom fields of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type 'orders' and there are a few custom fields attached to this post type.

When I query all orders like so:

`$orders = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'orders') );`

I don't get all the data I wish to get.

I have a tab custom field with a repeater in it. And I kinda need the data from the repeater. Anyone knows why I don't get this data in the dump of `$orders`?

Should my query be something else to get all this data?

EDIT

I've managed to query this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 41
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2016-02-29 14:30:33
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-02-29 14:30:33
                            [post_content] => <h2>Title!</h2>
                            Content.
                            [post_title] => Post Title
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => post-name
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2016-04-07 14:39:41
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-04-07 14:39:41
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => url
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => attracties
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => 
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1200
                )

        )
```

With this code:

```
$orders = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'orders') );

foreach ( $orders->posts as $all ) {
   $fields[] = get_field( 'planning', $all->ID );
}
```

What I basically need now is the `post_title` value from the attractie WP_Post Object and the `start` and `end` values.

Comment: Why did you tag advanced-custom-fields ? Are you using the plugin to attach some fields to your CPT ?

Comment: Yes I am using the ACF plugin to create my custom fields.

Comment: Check the answer. There are API's either in WP as well as in AFC and CPT UI plugins.

Answer (score 1):

So far so good, you are already creating custom query:

```
$loopargs = array( //in the array are arguments for custom query            
   'post_type' => 'orders', //your CPT
   'posts_per_page' => -1, //lets make WP show them all
   'orderby' => 'date', // newest
   'order' => 'DESC', //to the top
); 
$query = new WP_Query($loopargs);
```

Now let us loop through it:

```
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); //the_post loads for you current post in loop so that you can use functions like the_title(), the_content(), etc..
```

about ACF Plugin:

`the_field('your_field_name'); //will output field content directly`
`get_field('your_field_name'); //returns value from your custom field`
`get_fields(); //returns array of your fields`

Note that those ACF plugin functions will work in loop only, in our case when we set up the post with `the_post()` in `while` loop everytime. Otherwise you need to pass POST_ID as second (in first two) and as first parameters in ACF functions.

Also not that we have to reset your query after every custom one. And of course to end up our loop.

```
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

**References**

[Class Reference/WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

[Function Reference/the post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)

[ACF Documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/)

[Wordpress The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

**EDIT**

To access elements in your array from question you would do this:

```
$title = $array[0][0]['attractie']->post_title;
$start = $array[0][0]['start'];
$end = $array[0][0]['end'];
```

But this is really **NOT** the way you should do it.

Comment: Hello friend, I've updated OP with the code I am currently using. Check it out if you want.

Comment: I understand but do you have any idea how I can get those 3 values I explained in OP? the `post_title` of the attractie post opbject and the `start` and `end` value?

Comment: I bet `start` and `end` are custom fields right? If you would read the answer you could find out that everything can be done with one method `get_field('start')` inside loop, the thing you are missing in your code. Also please read Wordpress Codex.

Comment: I've tried this it works for `start` but doesn't for `end`, weirdly enough :/

Comment: Could you please show us how you did it? What works and what dont?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109049/discussion-between-frank-lucas-and-ksno).

Comment: checkout the chat if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to get acf fields try using like this

```
$orders = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'orders') );
foreach ( $orders->posts as $allPosts ) {
$field     = get_field( 'your field name', $allPosts->ID );
}
```

Comment: What should I fill in here:`'your field name'`? It's a bit confusing since I have a tab field `purchases` with repeater `agenda` in it and in the repeater a post object `name`. And I need the `name` value

Comment: add your repeater field name here.

Comment: so `$field` will give me an array of every value for every order?

Comment: you will get array of your repeater fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109079/discussion-between-owais-arain-and-frank-lucas).

Answer (score 0):

use get_post_custom function for  getting  list of  custom Fields

get_post_custom($post_id);